# VBA Worksheet Change is not working properly?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I wrote the following code in my worksheet and all ranges are in this same sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("DistMatrix")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim out1() As Double
    out1 = OutStat(bucket(Target), Range("RegScale"))
    FwdOut = outright(bucket(Target), Range("RegScale"))
    Call NewScatter(FwdOut, out1)
End If
End Sub
```

I want to run a called sub if I choose a cell in the range DistMatrix.

This is partly working. I have to click on a cell in the range as if I want to write in it and then afterwards pick another one for the called sub to run.

I want however the sub to run as soon as I pick the cell. I don't want to go have to double click it as if it were to edit it and then pick another one for it to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` instead.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("DistMatrix")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim out1() As Double
        out1 = OutStat(bucket(Target), Range("RegScale"))
        FwdOut = outright(bucket(Target), Range("RegScale"))
        Call NewScatter(FwdOut, out1)
    End If
End Sub
```